# Html css table width is growing up when td text is too long

Tags: html, css, html-table

Sorry for maybe many code, but why I set my table as fixed size, but when my content is too long it doesn't fit it's td width, but it is increasing table size from 810px to many many longer.... What's the problem? what is wrong?

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspasing="0" class="sortable zebra tablesorter tablesorter-default" id="articles-table">
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FN5Sn/

Here as it looks like now(and mu be so):

[image]

and here is what it looks like when I change some column content (so table is not 810px and is increasing over visible area)

[image]

But i must set, that table is fixed size, only for example 3-rd column size is getting smaller if table is to long.... How to do this?

NOTE:
  second column must be nowrap.... all other could be auto width

Comment: The screenshot it helpful. You really need to include a short working code sample (htlm+css) in your question in order for people to properly answer it.

Comment: @Diodeus fiddle is here... But it is huge, but i cant delete there something, becouese it can be important here...

Comment: @brabertaser1992: If your table relies of anything else to work correctly, you're doing it wrong. Try to give a short example, containing only the table (and related elements) and the CSS powering them.

Comment: have you tried overflow: hidden; ? That hides any extra text that overflows the column making your table bigger.

Comment: @RandomUs1r yes.... tried

Comment: @MadaraUchiha  i can't do this.... on my mind all is important there and i could ake mistake when cleaning code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove this from the offending TDs:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

Here is how you can use a mouseover effect to reveal hidden text that does not fit in a TD:

HTML:

```
<table width="100" border="1">
   <tr>
       <td>
           <div class="long">123 456 790-1122-4455</div>
       </td>
            <td>
           Other Data
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td {
  white-space:nowrap; 
  min-height:25px;
  position:relative;
  width:90px  
}

.long {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    width:90px;
}   

.long:hover {
   position:absolute;
   z-index:10; 
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:200px;
   background-color:#c0c0c0;
   border:1px solid #000000; 
   overflow-x:visible 
}
```

Comment: no no no.... they must be auto, but all table must be in 810px, and 2-d must be nowrap.... This is important... second td must be nowrap, but all other auto

Comment: @brabertaser1992: You can't have your cake and eat it too. If the line won't wrap, the width cannot be fixed. In a table, the content *will* push and ignore width and height rules if needed to make the content fit.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha so how to solve problem... Other ways? My second column must be always with nowrap

Comment: @brabertaser1992: Then it cannot be of fixed width in face of long content. That is all. I'm afraid there is not solution. Why does your second column *must* always be with nowrap?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha becouse it is article number, which must always be in-line

Comment: @brabertaser1992: In that case, why would it be long enough to mess with your table?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha becouse it is car parts.... it can be long, so that for example table is not 810px but 825px and this is bad.... maybe js could help?

Comment: One solution is to put DIV inside the TD and use overflow:hidden, then use mouseover to reveal the rest of the DIV.

Comment: I have added a code sample to my answer above. I hope this helps.

Comment: Soooooooperb. Love you bro :*